# Making Dedupe learn from existing label data

Tags: python-2.7, record-linkage, python-dedupe

I am aware that [Dedupe](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe) uses  Active learning to  remove duplicates and perform Record linkage.

However , I would like to know  if we can pass  excel sheet with already matched pairs(label data) as the input for active learning?

Answer (score 2):

Not directly.

You'll need to get your data into a format that [`markPairs`](https://dedupe.io/developers/library/en/latest/API-documentation.html#Dedupe.markPairs) can consume.

Something like:

```
labeled_examples = {'match'    : [],
                    'distinct' : [({'name' : 'Georgie Porgie'},
                                   {'name' : 'Georgette Porgette'})]
                    }
deduper.markPairs(labeled_examples)
```

We do provide a convenience function for getting spreadsheet data into this format [`trainingDataDedupe`](https://dedupe.io/developers/library/en/latest/API-documentation.html#trainingDataDedupe).

(I am an author of dedupe)

Comment: I was successfully able to generate the  first level  of results  by inputting the labeled data .

But As show in the Dedupe.io video ,how can  I further fine tune the results?

Comment: That functionality is not part of the dedupe library, but only part of  dedupe.io.

Comment: Thanks for your  help.

Comment: what is the meaning of confidence score  being > 1.0 ?
eg: 0.84, 1.23 ,4.56, 7.65, 3.4

Comment: This question seems far afield.

Comment: I am really surprise that dedupe is performing well with less data(10%) and Bad with more data training data(100%)
How should we choose the number of samples for training ?